# Can my friend's pc connect to my PostgreSQL? If yes, how?

Tags: postgresql

By far NONE answered my question, so i'm stuck here...

Basically i made a program (it's connected to my *PostgreSQL* database) which, depending on the user input, it will change tables contents in the database. It's a sort of Register/Login sistem. **(click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuf2CLerbHYFI_OEv-Hrc9xKqYff9lyl/view?usp=sharing) if you want to see the script)**. When i run it on my pc *(Windows 10 x64)* it works like a charm. But when a friend of mine *(Windows 10 x64)* tries to run it (on a different network) it gives him this error:

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host “192.168.1.113” and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

(if it can help you, i tried MySQL too, but i got the same result... my friend cannot access to my database!)

So, I was asking my self ***"Is it even possible allow other devices to access my database from other networks? If yes, how can I do it?"***

Comment: You need a static IP for that, or at the very least the two devices need to share the same network like WiFi. It's for the same reasons why we can't treat our phones as servers, despite them having sufficient Ram and Storage. And everytime you connect to the WiFi, it uses assigns you an IP Address from a pool of IP addresses available to it.

Comment: Traditionally we have cloud hosting services such as heroku-- which provide support for Postgres, you can try that, it's free of cost as well.

Comment: Then anyone will be available to connect to it, provided they have the credentials that heroku will provide you with.

Comment: OK, thank you so much! I will try that and i will tell you if it works! (Do you have some suggestion to tell me about Heroku?)

Comment: Maybe this helps, I did work on it a couple years back. https://github.com/EverWinter23/postgres-heroku

Comment: You will have to create an account on heroku and follow this tutorial from that point on. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: I already created an account. I'm so excited!!

Comment: @frozenOne I have another question... I've just seen that the Heroku database memory space is of only 8mb... I wanted my database to use my HDD memory space to keep all the data... Is there any method or i have to buy Heraku database memory?

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: My HDD is about 1TB, is there any method to store the database's data on my HDD instead of using Haroku's HDDs?

Comment: There is, but then we have access problems, your hardrive is not available to the internet for access, locally yes, but then others won't be able to access it. Don't worry too much about data storage, you can always expand vertically, other hosting sites are AWS, Digital Ocean-- important term is "hosted database services", hosted means accessible through the internet.

Heroku is great for prototyping/demos, once you get that out of the way, you can move to something more robust like AWS, or Azure, or other cloud providers, it's extremely simple.

Comment: and AWS, Azure are expensive... right?

Comment: Plus, I have taken a look at the script, and it's all text based, in 10MB you could easily host upwards of 50,000 user emails/passwords. DB are somewhat like text files, and generally text files aren't that big, unless you're dealing with huge amount of traffic.

Comment: AWS isn't expensive, if you are a student/teacher, you can get credits for one year for free, you just need to provide them with your student/teacher ID.

Comment: Google Compute services are free for students as well.

Comment: @frozenOne I'm thinking about creating a Social Media, so that all images will be stored in a database. so, i don't think 8mb will be enough. By the way i will have a look to Google Compute services!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd advise against that, we use databases to store metadata, text based data, data that you need to run queries upon, for storing images what services like instagram, pinterest do-- is they store images on services like s3 which are inexpensive, [because databases are extremely expensive]. Plust the amount of images generate per second, should you receive that amount of traffic would be astronomical.

What they do is they store the images on s3-- it's like your hard disk, but hosted on the internet, and then store the path in the database, and when someone asks for that image, we serve it from s3.

Comment: So basically there's no way to host my HDD on the internet

Comment: Get a static IP address, then you can host anything you want. You can even host the whole thing on your system, you'll need to keep it connected to the internet from all the time for it to be available 24x7, we go for services like AWS, Azure and all because they provide us with benefits like replications. What happens if my hard disk crashes? What happens if my internet goes out? Don't worry about this too much. If you hit that amount of traffic, you'll get funded, generate revenue and be able to afford cloud hosting services.

Answer (score 2):

192.168.*.* is for local network addresses. You would not expect it to be reachable from another network. You would have to figure out what your real address is.  For example, by going to https://whatismyipaddress.com/ or just Googling "what is my IP address".

Then you have the question of how often that address changes (which is up to your ISP) and how to get the connection past your home router, which will probably either block it, or at least not route it to your database server, without special configuration to do port-forwarding.  This is a basic networking task and at the moment is not specific to PostgreSQL.

Your ISP may also block the connection, as hosting servers on your standard home ISP plan is likely against the terms of service.  Although most of them allow it if the traffic never comes to their attention due to high usage or due to abuse complaints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My public-IP has never changed. I'm a beginner so i don't know  what **"how to get the connection past your home router, which will probably either block it, or at least not route it to your database server, without special configuration to do port-forwarding."** means. I think i have to learn a lot!

Comment: Yes, as you have been told on the other versions of this question you have posted. You need to spend time learning basic networking and Web services. When you have done that and need assistance with a specific question, then do so.

Comment: So, in short words, hosting my HDD or make my friend connect to my database is very difficult if not impossible!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver okay okay, thank you for your advice!

Comment: You need to be able to configure your home router.  Every router is different, so we can't provide you with blanket instructions.  You can probably find instructions just by googling your router's model number and "port forwarding" or something like that.  Or just go to the router's configuration panel (often http://192.168.0.1) and read the descriptions on the screen.  Be careful, don't let the bad guys take over your network.